# Under ARC, property and declare of Objective-C confused

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Under ARC,
if I define a ivar like this:

```
@interface ObjectA : NSObject {
    id A;
}

@property(nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) id A;
```

What's the property of A? strong or unsafe_unretained?

Comment: you just set "unsafe_unretained"

Comment: I rarely use gtalk. If you have qq, you can add 50602724.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you implement it. There are two ways you can go about doing it:

- Using `@synthesize A;` or `@synthesize A = __A;` In this case it's `__unsafe_unretained`, because the ownership spec of the property trumps the ownership spec of the ivar<sup>1</sup>.
- Manually writing `A` and `setA`. In this case, the result will depend on the kind of backing variable that you choose for your implementation.<sup>2</sup>

Here is a [link](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) to the documentation that spells out the rules of how the ownership of properties is determined. See Section 4.1.1.

> <sup>1</sup> If the associated instance variable already exists, then its ownership qualification must equal the ownership of the property; otherwise, the instance variable is created with that ownership qualification [of the property].
>
> <sup>2</sup> A property's specified ownership is preserved in its metadata, but otherwise the meaning is purely conventional unless the property is synthesized.

Comment: I'm interested... do you have a documentation link?

Comment: That's petty interesting and prevent a lot of mistakes here. Thank you. one more question about ARC, I have to set all the retain member to nil in the didunload function?

Comment: @Eout My first answer was wrong in one place. I found an explanation in the docs and corrected the answer - please take a look.

Comment: Got it. Sorry for the poor English. Reading Document is a little hard to me but I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

From apple doc:

Variable Qualifiers

You use the following lifetime qualifiers for variables just like you would, say, const.

```
__strong
__weak
__unsafe_unretained
__autoreleasing
```

`__strong` is the default. An object remains “alive” as long as there is a strong pointer to it.
`__weak` specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive. A weak reference is set to nil when there are no strong references to the object.
`__unsafe_unretained` specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive and is not set to nil when there are no strong references to the object. If the object it references is deallocated, the pointer is left dangling.
`__autoreleasing` is used to denote arguments that are passed by reference (id *) and are autoreleased on return.
You should decorate variables correctly. When using qualifiers in an object variable declaration, the correct format is: